# When is a multiplicative commutator conjugate to its inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Recall that elements $a$ and $b$ in $G$ is called *conjugate* if $a=gbg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$. Let us consider an element of form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Then, the inverse of $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is $yxy^{-1}x^{-1}$. I would like to ask when $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is conjugate to $yxy^{-1}x^{-1}$.

For instance, if $x=x^{-1}$ and $y=y^{-1}$, then $$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=x(yxy^{-1}x^{-1})x^{-1}.$$  However, I do not know the problem in general. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is -x? You work in a group.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I rewrite @Martin Brandenburg.

Comment: Note that $[x,y]^g=[x^g,y^g]$. In particular, if there exists $g$ whose square commutes with $x$ and $g^{-1}xg=y$, then you get the equality you want. Or if $[x,y]$ is of order $2$. There are many instances where it will happen, but it will not be true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_p$ be the Heisenberg group, which is a group of matrices of form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&a&c \\ 0&1& b\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

with $a,b,c$ taken modulo $p$ (where $p$ is an odd prime). This group is not abelian, so there are non-trivial commutators.

At the same time, elements with $a=b=0$ form a subgroup, which is actually the center of our group. As the quotient $H_p/Z(H_p)$ has $p^2$ elements, it is abelian, so all commutators lie in $Z(H_p)$.

Now non-trivial elements in the center have no other conjugates than themselves, and are not equal to own inverses, so in fact $[x,y]$ and $[y,x]$ are not conjugate whenever $[x,y]$ is non-trivial.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “are not equal to own conjugates”. Did you mean to write “inverse” instead of “conjugate”? (This is then true for $p ≠ 2$.)

Comment: You need $p$ odd. Otherwise $[x,y]$ has order $2$ and is conjugate to its inverse (itself).

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits in my answer. As far as I know the Heisenberg group is defined mainly for odd primes (for instance when $p=2$ the exponent of the group is not $p$, so we lose an interesting property), but it still is important to write it.

Comment: The group with $p=2$ is the dihedral group of order 8, which is also generated by two elements of order $2$ whose commutator is central and has order 2. The presentation can be done uniformly for all $p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, of course you're right. Perhaps my perspective is biased – the first time I encountered Heisenberg groups was in a problem "We know that groups of exponent 2 are abelian, what about groups of exponent $p$?". Then looking at $D_8$ as a Heisenberg group isn't the preffered way. But this is quite obscure and arbitrary, so again: yes, sure, you're right.